# Cost of setting variable vs conditional checking

Tags: javascript

I have encountered the folowing situation and confused about the best approach in such a case:

**approach 1**

```
foo(x){
    if(x === undefined) {
        x = 0;
    }
    //other stuff
}
```

Suppose that there is no problem with setting x = 0 without checking its value. In this case, I think it is better and not too costy to set the x instead of checking its value using an `if` block. For this reason, can we say that (if there is no problem to set x value at that stage), it is better to set its value directly as its time complexity is smaller than codition block (in each case its value will be set and there is no difference between memory usages of these conditions).

**approach 2**

```
foo(x){
    x = 0;
    //other stuff
}
```

Comment: Is this java, c# or javascript?

Comment: @corsiKa and how is this a time complexity question?

Comment: [For performance evaluation read this](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: @corsiKa Does it make sense?

Comment: Please choose one language.

Comment: note that the two snippets do two fundamentally different things.

Comment: @VLAZ I know javascript has a notion of `undefined` as opposed to java and c# - it was an educated guess.

Comment: @luk2302 Then, as you know javascript, what about your comments regarding to this issue?

Comment: I said it already: the two snippets do two fundamentally different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time complexity for both approaches is the same.

Time complexity is based-off of input size. As the size of the input increases, the time complexity increases.

Neither approach 1 nor approach 2 will change with the input size, therefore they are both O(1). The if-statement is performing a simple comparison, which is always O(1).

So in the grand-scheme of things, they are both O(1) and the difference will be so minimal you will never notice.

Answer (score 1):

I feel that you're confused on what time complexity really is.

Everything you've mentioned here has an equivalent time complexity. Consider the two following snippets of code:

```
int x = 0;
```

and this one

```
int y = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 1_000_000_000; i++) {
    y += i;
}
int x = y;
```

One clearly takes longer than the other - adding up a billion different numbers takes a LONG time in comparison. However, they are the same time complexity, namely constant time. That is to say the input will not change how long it takes to run.

You're talking about the difference in time that is sooooo small between these two operations that you never need to worry about it. Instead, worry that your logic is correct and produces the correct output for the given inputs.

Comment: Good explanations, thanks. But I thought that the time complexity of `int x = 0;` is O[1) and the second one in your answer is O(n) where n = i (I look at the perspective of `y += i;`. Am I wrong? If I look at `int x = y;` then it would be O(1) again and there is of course no difference.

Comment: Nope, `i` will max at a constant, thus it is O(1). It would be the same as if you wrote the million lines of code out. No input will change the billion to anything else.